# C++ constructor with a const argument

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, constants

I just wondered what's the difference between having a constructor with `const char* c` or `char* const c` as a parameter?
If I swap `char*` and `const` in header and source file it isn't a problem but when I mix them it won't compile, saying there is no such overloaded constructor.

When I use my own class for a copy constructor the compiler doesn't seem to bother if I have `MyClass const &other` and `const MyClass &other` mixed..

Can anyone enlighten me please? :)

Comment: The problem is that you're not using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: If you're going to post code, you should at least post code that illustrates the question you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This record `const char *c` declares pointer c that points to an object of type `const char`. That is using this pointer you may not change the object that refered to by the pointer.

This record `char * const c` declares `const` pointer c that points to a non-const object of type `char`. You may not change the pointer itself but you may change the object refered to by the pointer.

There is a difference between declaring pointers and references. Though there is used term "constant reference" strictly speaking references themselves may not be constant. According to the C++ grammar

```
ptr-operator:
* attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seq
& attribute-specifier-seqopt
```

references do not contain cv-qualifier-seq. So for example this record

```
Airplane & const other
```

will be incorrect and the compiler shall issue an error.
As for these records

```
const Airplane & other
Airplane const & other
```

then they are equivalent the same way as equivalent the recirds below

```
const char *c
char const *c
```

Comment: Ah thanks, couldn't remember that!
Visual Studio compiles Airplane const &other without a word..

Answer (score 2):

Think of the `*` as a "fence". What's before it in the declaration defines the type that the pointer refers *to*. What's after the `*` defines the pointer itself. For this case, it's easiest to read things backwards (translating `*` as "pointer to"), so `char const *t` is read (from back to front) as: "t is a pointer to a const char". Likewise, `char *const t` is read as: "t is a const pointer to a char."

1. `char *const` means the pointer *itself* is `const` (can't be modified), but the char(s) it points *at* **can** be modified.
2. `char const *` or `const char *` are equivalent to each other. Both mean the pointer itself can be modified, but what it points *at* cannot.

Substituting a different type for `char` doesn't change that basic idea.

The same is true with a reference: `const T &` means a reference to a `const T`, so you can't modify the `T` that it refers to. In the case of a reference, you can't modify the reference itself to refer to a different object, so `T & const` doesn't make any real sense (and isn't allowed).

Answer (score 0):

`const` applies to the type to its left (or to its right if there is nothing on its left), so `const char *` and `char const *` are the same and mean that the characters cannot change, but the pointer can, whereas `char * const` means that the characters can change but the pointer cannot

Answer (score 0):

The order in which const and char* are written actually make a difference. If you have `const char*` in your header but `char* const` in your source file, you will get an error because the compiler won't regard these as the same.

`const char* p` means that p points to a char that is constant. We can alter where p points to, but we can never alter the contents stored at p.

`char* const p` means that p is a constant pointer and is pointing to a char. We can alter the contents stored at p, but we cannot alter where p points to.

`const char* const p` means that p is a constant pointer to a constant char. We cannot alter where p points to nor can we alter the contents at p. Hope this is helpful!